# Почему при шаринге с сайта в фейсбук отправляется картинка другой новости?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, соцсети, opengraph

Есть сайт на **wordpress**, где в шапке настроил мета-теги для **twitter** и **facebook** заданные с помощью `open graph`. (проблема с выводом картинки у фесбука)

Сам код:

```
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@http://site.ru">
  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@site.ru">
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>">
  <meta property="og:type" content="image/jpeg">
        <meta property="og:url"  content="http://site.ru">
  <meta property="og:title"  content="<?php the_title(); ?>">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php while (have_posts()):the_post();
  $out_excerpt = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "'" ,"\""), "", get_the_excerpt());
  echo $out_excerpt; endwhile; ?>">
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php while (have_posts()):the_post();
  $out_excerpt = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "'" ,"\""), "", get_the_excerpt());
  echo $out_excerpt; endwhile; ?>">
  <?php if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ))
  {
  $default_image='site.ru/logo.png';
  echo '<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="' . $default_image . '">';
  echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '">';
  }
  else
  {
  $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
  echo '<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '">';
  echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '">';
  } echo "\n"; ?>
  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
```

Вот в таком виде выводится на сайте

```
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@http://site.ru">
  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@site.ru">
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Content">
  <meta property="og:type" content="image/jpeg">
        <meta property="og:url"  content="http://site.ru">
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Title">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="description">
       <meta property="og:description" content="description">
  <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://site.ru/img-768x500.jpg"><meta property="og:image" content="http://site.ru/img-768x500.jpg">
  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <link rel="pingback" href="http://site.ru/xmlrpc.php">
```

При шаринге в **твиттере** все новости выводятся отлично, а вот 
[в отладчике facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) пишет вот такую ошибку:

> Свойство «og:image» должно быть указано в явном порядке, даже если его
>   значение может быть вычислено на основании других тегов.

и выводит каждый раз одну и ту же картинку (не новости, котрую постим!), причем не лого, как можно было подумать, а взятую с другой новости. (хотя в коде выводится правильная, как и для твиттера) 
В чем может быть ошибка и как можно это исправить?

Comment: А ваш сайт не на https? Кроме того у меня была когда то проблема - нужно было явно указать высоту и ширину картинки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По всей видимости, ошибку нашел - заменил url корня сайта `<meta property="og:url"  content="http://site.ru">` на url конкретной страницы `<meta property="og:url"  content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">` (похоже, что изображения кешируются в зависимости от url страницы) и еще написал тип контента в зависимости от страницы

```
<?php if (is_single()) { ?> 
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<?php } else { ?> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />  
<?php } ?> 
<meta property="og:url"  content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Также проверьте, возможно у вас стоит canonical.
У меня данная ошибка происходила именно из-за него.
Так как facebook видит какая страница является канонической и у нее пробует взять изображение.
Так что просто в  пропишите корректный canonical.

" />